# Avoid Multiple Canvas view overlap each other in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose-canvas

I am building a timeline view. I have a list which is coming server. I just mocked 4 items on the list to show the view possibilities. The problem is having that my canvas view is overlap to each other. If I used the background color, it overlaps last text of each item with another view. I don't know what is the best way to use single canvas.

[image]

I tried this piece of code

**CanvasView**

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalTextApi::class)
@Composable
fun CanvasView() {
    val titleTextMeasurer = rememberTextMeasurer()
    val timeLineList = getTimeLineDataList()
    val typeToColorMap = mapOf(
        "app" to Color.Black,
        "link" to Color.Blue
    )
    val titleText = AnnotatedString("Hello world!!")
    val titleTextLayoutResult = remember {
        titleTextMeasurer.measure(titleText, TextStyle(fontSize = 16.sp))
    }
    val endPadding = with(LocalDensity.current) { 10.dp.toPx() }
    val circleSize = with(LocalDensity.current) { 6.dp.toPx() }

    Column(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {

        timeLineList.forEachIndexed { index, timeLineDataItem ->

            val multipleString = buildAnnotatedString {
                timeLineDataItem.items.forEachIndexed { _, item ->
                    val (text, type) = item
                    withStyle(SpanStyle(color = typeToColorMap[type] ?: Color.Red)) {
                        append("$text\n")
                    }
                }
            }

            val multipleTextLayoutResult = remember {
                titleTextMeasurer.measure(multipleString, TextStyle(fontSize = 14.sp, lineHeight = 1.3.em))
            }

            val canvasHeightInDp = LocalDensity.current.run {
                titleTextLayoutResult.size.height.toDp() +
                        multipleTextLayoutResult.size.height.toDp()
            }
            val viewMarginTop = LocalDensity.current.run {
                24.dp.toPx()
            }
            val subTitleTopMargin = LocalDensity.current.run { 12.dp.toPx() }

            CanvasContent(
                canvasHeightInDp,
                viewMarginTop,
                subTitleTopMargin,
                titleTextLayoutResult,
                multipleTextLayoutResult,
                circleSize,
                endPadding,
                index != 0,
                index != timeLineList.lastIndex,
            )
        }
    }
}
```

**CanvasContent**

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalTextApi::class)
@Composable
fun CanvasContent(
    canvasHeightInDp: Dp,
    viewMarginTop: Float,
    subTitleTopMargin: Float,
    titleTextLayoutResult: TextLayoutResult,
    multipleTextLayoutResult: TextLayoutResult,
    circleSize: Float,
    endPadding: Float,
    firstItem: Boolean,
    lastItem: Boolean,
) {
    Canvas(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(Color.LightGray)
            .height(canvasHeightInDp)
    ) {
        val circleX = (center.x / 2) + (titleTextLayoutResult.size.width / 2) - endPadding
        drawText(
            textLayoutResult = titleTextLayoutResult,
            topLeft = Offset(
                x = center.x - titleTextLayoutResult.size.width / 2,
                y = viewMarginTop,
            )
        )
        drawText(
            textLayoutResult = multipleTextLayoutResult,
            topLeft = Offset(
                x = center.x - titleTextLayoutResult.size.width / 2,
                y = viewMarginTop + (titleTextLayoutResult.size.height / 2) + subTitleTopMargin,
            )
        )
        if (firstItem) {
            drawLine(
                color = Color.Black,
                start = Offset(x = circleX, y = 0F),
                end = Offset(
                    x = circleX,
                    y = viewMarginTop + titleTextLayoutResult.size.height / 2 - circleSize
                ),
                strokeWidth = 2.dp.toPx(),
            )
        }
        if (lastItem) {
            drawLine(
                color = Color.Black,
                start = Offset(
                    x = circleX,
                    y = viewMarginTop + titleTextLayoutResult.size.height / 2 + circleSize
                ),
                end = Offset(x = circleX, y = size.height),
                strokeWidth = 2.dp.toPx(),
            )
        }
        drawCircle(
            color = Color.Black,
            radius = circleSize,
            center = Offset(circleX, viewMarginTop + titleTextLayoutResult.size.height / 2)
        )
    }
}
```

Adding mock data

```
data class TimeLineData(val items: List<Pair<String, String>>)

private fun getTimeLineDataList(): List<TimeLineData> {
    val firstList = listOf(
        Pair("Text 1", "app"),
        Pair("Text 2", "link"),
    )
    val secondList = listOf(
        Pair("Text 1", "app"),
        Pair("Text 2", "link"),
        Pair("Text 3", "app"),
        Pair("Text 4", "link"),
        Pair("Text 5", ""),
    )
    val thirdList = listOf(
        Pair("Text 1", "app"),
    )
    val fourList = listOf(
        Pair("Text 1", "app"),
        Pair("Text 2", "link"),
        Pair("Text 3", "app"),
    )
    return listOf(
        TimeLineData(firstList),
        TimeLineData(secondList),
        TimeLineData(emptyList()),
        TimeLineData(thirdList),
        TimeLineData(fourList),
    )
}
```

**Expected output**

No view is overlap with each other.

[image]

Above image is rough diagram of my timeline view. Thanks